# Google Charts doesn't draw chart

Tags: php, charts, xampp, google-visualization

I'm trying to bring some informations from a database hosted in xampp, to be more exactly, i'm trying to draw a chart with google charts where shows the count of students in determined course of a university.

But the chart simply doesn't appears in div id="chart-one". What can be the problem?

Heres is the code: in php:

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.

      function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDateTable([
            ['Course', 'Number of Students']
        <?php
            include 'connection.php';

            $sql = "SELECT course, COUNT(course) as 'students' from Students GROUP BY course";
            $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            while($data =  mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
                $course = $data['course'];
                $students = $dados['students'];
                ?>

                ['<?php echo $course?>', <?php echo $students ?>],
                
          <?php } ?>
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Number of students per course',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-one'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart-one"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

connection.php fil:

```php
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "unifesspa";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed!" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: First thing to do: Make sure the **last element** of the data table **doesn't** contain the comma at the end : ['<?php echo $course?>', <?php echo $students ?>] `,`

Comment: Check the javascript console on your browser to see if you have syntax errors there.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Yeung Here is the browser error
```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDateTable is not a constructor
    at drawChart (charts.php:19:20)```

Comment: `arrayToDateTable` should likely be `arrayToDataTable` - note `data` not `date`

Answer (score 1):

The output of your javascript array output is not right. Also it would be prone to escaping error if your data has quotes.

It would be less error-prone if you construct your whole data in PHP, then use json_encode to encode it as the 2-dimension array you want.

```php
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT course, COUNT(course) as 'students' from Students GROUP BY course";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$chart_data = [
    ['Course', 'Number of Students'],
];

while($data =  mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $chart_data[] = [$data['course'], $data['students']];
}

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($chart_data); ?>);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Number of students per course',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-one'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart-one"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks more correclty, but the error stills remains. In browser console appears:

```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDateTable is not a constructor     at drawChart (charts.php:19:20)```

When I delete 'new' in line:
 ```var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-one'));```

The error on browser is:
```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.arrayToDateTable is not a function
    at drawChart (charts.php:19:41)```

Comment: Try removing the `new` keyword from the lines the complains it's not a constructor.

Comment: `arrayToDateTable` should likely be `arrayToDataTable` - note `data` not `date`